# JAVA - length() in a for loop

Tags: java, string, loops, for-loop, complexity-theory

Is it bad to use 'str.length()' in a for loop or any kind of loop?
Does this make O(n^2) complexity?
If it is bad, we can assign it to a variable and use the variable instead, right?

Comment: *"Does this make O(n^2) complexity?"* - I have no idea why you'd think that. And no, it's not bad (why do you think that?)

Answer (score 1):

No.
String is immutable, and length() has O(1) complexity. Simply returns already initialised number.

https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java

EDIT: thanks Real Sceptic